# How to get old SSH fingerprint format?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

SSH has gone through several fingerprint formats and visualization methods.  There are MD5 and SHA256 for formats. Hex, Base64 and ramdomart are different visualizations.  For a short time, however, there was another visualization format that appears to use random five-letter words.

```
8192 ximah-tuciz-barit-nukat-milyn-binoz-zymyl-rymyt-litos-tedeb-kaxex GlitchV2 (RSA)
```

It appears to generate the word in the format consonant-vowel-consonant-vowel-consonant, which seems actually to be a reasonable way to generate basically pronounceable but random words.

I have several lists of ssh fingerprints in this format, but cannot find a reference to what or how they were generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [Bubble Babble](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/one/bubblebabble/spec/jrtrjwzi/draft-huima-01.txt) encoding of the SHA-1 digest of the public key blob.

You can use `ssh-keygen -B` to generate such a fingerprint for a given public key:

```
ssh-keygen -Bf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank-you.  Couldn't find this anywhere.  For extra points, do you know of a way to get OpenSSH to print it in this format when VisualHostKey is set to yes?

Comment: Patch sshconnect.c replacing SSH_FP_RANDOMART with SSH_FP_BUBBLEBABBLE in all 3 locations. Otherwise it won't do that; this feature is exclusive to ssh-keygen. (It's likely there only for compatibility with other SSH clients.)